# How do I create an IMediaPlaybackSource from a Stream, so as to set a MediaPlayer source without using the obsolete SetStreamSource method?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to develop a UWP application that will speak text to the user via a `Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer`. I have this code that currently works:

```
    private async Task Speak(string text)
    {
        var audio = await _Speech.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);
        player.SetStreamSource(audio);
        player.Play();
    }
```

However, this causes a compiler warning: `'MediaPlayer.SetStreamSource(IRandomAccessStream)' is obsolete: 'Use Source instead of SetStreamSource.  For more info, see MSDN.`

However, I can't find on MSDN how to convert the `SpeechSynthesisStream` that `SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync` generates to a `IMediaPlaybackSource` that the `MediaPlayer` wants. The `Windows.Media.Core.MediaStreamSource` class looks promising, but it wants a `IMediaStreamDescriptor` which I have no idea how to get...

How do I replicate the functionality of this simple three-liner without using deprecated methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the [MediaSource.CreateFromStream()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediasource.createfromstream#Windows_Media_Core_MediaSource_CreateFromStream_Windows_Storage_Streams_IRandomAccessStream_System_String_) method for this purpose.

```
private async Task Speak(string text)
{
    var audio = await _Speech.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);
    player.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(audio);
    player.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync returns a SpeechSynthesisStream object that you can use. This example from the MSDN documentation should lead you in the right direction

```
   SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Hello World");

   mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesizer

Comment: I never had any problems creating the SpeechSynthesisStream, it was converting it to a IMediaPlaybackSource that I couldn't figure out.